# Workflow tool for DevOps

Tags: software-development, workflow

I'm looking for a locally installed tool for creating and managing workflows for DevOps work.

Please note I'm **not** looking for a CI/CD tool such as Jenkins. I'm not interested in building pipelines but in building workflows. Of course I can do whatever with a pipeline as well but I'm finding that my work as devops consists of workflows. These workflows include automated steps (sometimes running a pipeline) and manual steps as well.

I've selected some options to look from [this list on GitHub](https://github.com/meirwah/awesome-workflow-engines) but I figured I can ask here for recommendations.

I have very basic requirements:

- Can run a script in chosen script engine (bash, pwsh, etc.) as part of a task in the workflow. Show output, error output etc.
- Has a nice graphical UI and the workflow is manageable/editable in a graph.
- You can clearly see states of individual steps in a running instance of a workflow. Passed, failed, etc.
- Has a support for a **manual step**. This is an important requirement for me. If there is a manual step, the workflow engine must wait for a human intervention either to just confirm something or to give the workflow engine necessary data that are used in further steps.

Bonus points:

- User, role, permission management
- Workflow categorization
- OIDC authentication

In the list mentioned above I see `Airflow` and `DolphinScheduler` have most stars but they seem to be built specifically for working with data so I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Several hours in my research I think I found exactly what I wanted - [Windmill](https://www.windmill.dev/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).